# Word (subject) for the way or style of doing something

Tags: synonyms

I think I can say "There are different ways of eating a cake" or "There are different styles of eating a cake".

Is there also a subject that replaces "way of [anything]"? E.g. if I want to list all ways how to eat a cake, I want to write "Eating-Ways" but in a way that sounds better. I am not a native speaker, so is there any word that I can use to replace the "Ways" above to make it sound better and maybe even more generic?

Comment: perhaps you can use 'manners' or 'methods'

Comment: What do you  mean by "different ways of eating  a cake"? Can you make an example.

Comment: I can eat the cake with my hands, or with my mouth only. I can also use a spoon or I can blend the cake and drink it - okay that is not eating anymore I guess but I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: _Manner_ is the technical word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure/method/process or ,even, "mode" may substitute "ways of anything". But,better stick to a phrase than one-word-substitution.:-various(styles/modes/methods) of eating.

Comment: Disagree on mode.  Procedure and process are also outré if you're talking about eating cake.  No one's going to call it a procedure any more than they'll call it an algorithm.

Comment: I agree on mode. While it is very generic and may not sound appropriate (or at least there are better alternatives, like *manner* for eating the cake) it is a good fit in my case.